# best way to configure NSG rule for mobile app client and Service fabric hosted API

Tags: azure-service-fabric, network-security-groups

We have following structure for my application. currently we have used Any for both source and destination (on port 3389) while defining NSG rule for our Service Fabric to allow calls from mobile app. But our security team has raised concerns on Any-Any rule. Is there any way to optimize this?

[image]

Note: our mobile app is public and anyone can download from app store.

Answer (score 0):

Any to Any rule open SF for attach really so you should limit the IP from your traffic manager given your current model.

Azure API management already have build in support for Service Fabric so my suggestion is to remove the traffic manager between then API management and SF. Then you can do is to limit the traffic to SF only from the API management which is much easier.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-api-management-overview

Authentication requirement you can delegate that to the API management ie validate JWT token

Comment: We implement active-active scenarios so we cant remove the traffic manager. Also how your suggestion will solve the Any-Any NSG issue? As mentioned in the diagram we already use API management.

Comment: Each API management will have an IP address. Then you can have NSG which only allow traffic from API management IP to reach back end services. If you want to have more control ie load balancing, reverse proxy etc on the traffic from API management to back end service then i will suggest to use different tool ie traefik or caddy. Hope this helps :-)